# Amazon AWS s3fs mount problem on Fedora 14

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, fedora, s3fs

I successfully compiled and installed s3fs (http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) on my Fedora 14 machine. I included the password credentials in /etc/ as specified in the guide. When I run:

sudo /usr/bin/s3fs bucket_name /mnt/bucket_name/

it runs successfully. (note: the bucket name is the same as the folder name in /mnt/). When I run ls in /mnt/ I get the error "ls: cannot access bucket_name: Permission denied". When I run

sudo chmod 640 /mnt/bucket_name

I get "chmod: changing permissions of `bucket_name': Input/output error". When I reboot the machine I can access the folder /mnt/bucket_name normally but it is not mapped to the s3 bucket.

So, basically I have two questions. 1) How do I access the folder (/mnt/bucket_name) as usual after I mount it to the s3 bucket and 2) How can I keep it mounted even after machine restart.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in amazon s3, bucket names are 'global' to all s3 users, so, be sure that the bucket name that you're using is your bucket

furthermore, need to create the bucket first with another s3 tool

to keep it mounted after machine restart, stitch it into /etc/fstab as per http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon (search for 'fstab' in the comments)

Comment: I have already created the bucket. My problem is with the permissions.

Comment: can check /var/log/messages; also, sounds like there is a amazon s3 accessId/secretAccessKey mismatch

Comment: one other thing: are you mounting the bucket as 'root' and trying to access it using a non-root account? if so then try the default_permissions and/or allow_other options

Comment: The mount point owner (use `chown` to set owner) and s3fs mount option `default_acl` are also very important. `allow_other` simply lets any local system user to write to the mount point no matter owner. (sets a 0777 permission). `uid` and `gid` fstab options may also be set to allow only one user to write - then you could omit `allow_other`.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `allow_other` to your command, this fixed it for me.

```
/usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other mybucketname mymountpoint
```